# How can I change color in gradient inside selector inside inset?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have following drawable XML:

**background_view_rounded_top.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetBottom="0.0px"
    android:insetLeft="1.0px"
    android:insetRight="1.0px"
    android:insetTop="1.0px" >

    <selector>
        <item android:state_pressed="true">
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:angle="270.0"
                    android:endColor="@color/base_end_color_pressed"
                    android:startColor="@color/base_start_color_pressed" />

                <corners
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="0.0dip"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="0.0dip"
                    android:radius="2.0dip"
                    android:topLeftRadius="10.0dip"
                    android:topRightRadius="10.0dip" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:angle="270.0"
                    android:endColor="@color/base_end_color_default"
                    android:startColor="@color/base_start_color_default" />

                <corners
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="0.0dip"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="0.0dip"
                    android:radius="2.0dip"
                    android:topLeftRadius="11.0dip"
                    android:topRightRadius="11.0dip" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>

</inset>
```

I want to change its `startColor` and `endColor`. I can't do this by simply copying this xml few times, because I will use this drawable many times and having dozens of xml like this is not an option. So I want to reuse this xml and change those colors in code.

I also have background_view_rounded_bottom/middle/single and also version without rounded corners, and all those xmls should have parametrized colors as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.java) out, there's quite a bit of additional code but it seems to demonstrate how to create a drawable and gradient drawable in code... look around line 159. 
 By making it programmatically you can change gradient dynamically

Answer (score -4):

Try using a gradient that i had created. here you can easily set start and end colour,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#A5A5A5"
          android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:angle="90" />
    <solid android:color="#50FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: just replace your xml with this one.! what else you need.!

Comment: You didn't understand my question. You still need dozens of xmls to alter color.

Comment: which color you need to alter and for what purpose. I am not able get what you are saying.!

Comment: I need to change startColor and endColor many times across my application. This will not help me, because you hardcoded your values. And stop yelling.